# Adding platform specific property for textinput in React Native

Tags: react-native

I am having lot of TextInput in my React Native app. For IOS, i need to add color property to '#000' that because otherwise the input values shows just white and it's not visible. But if i keep this color property for android, the app crashes. So, i need to give platform specific condition for IOS only. Now how can i do that. Here's the TextInput example:

```js
<TextInput
  value={this.state.username}
  placeholder={Languages.email}
  placeholderStyle={{
    fontFamily: Constants.headerRegular,
    color: '#A4A9AF',
  }}
  onChangeText={username => this.setState({ username })}
  label={Languages.userOrEmail}
  style={styles.textBox}
  
  // Need to edit the following line
  // color= {Platform.OS} === 'ios' ? '#000'
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done via importing `Platform`, you can check [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/platform). It allows you to check the OS.  You was almost correct, but you needed to write

```
<TextInput
  style={styles.textBox}
  color={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? '#000' : 'value for false'} //<-- color
  condition all goes inside parentheses
/>
```

If you will be using iOS and Android only, then for 'value for false' you can specify a color for when the condition eliminates to false, meaning OS is not iOS and most likely android. For example:

```
<TextInput
  style={styles.textBox}
  color={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? '#000' : '#fff'} //<-- or any other value
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Color attribute in style should work :

```
<TextInput
   style={{color: Platform.OS === 'ios'? "#000":"other for android"}}
```

and the fact that value is not visible in iOS is probably caused by dark mode in iOS

Comment: Yes it is for the dark mode but adding in style won't solve the issue. It has to be color property to TextInput.

Comment: I use color in style to solve dark mode issue, just test again plz + I don't find color prop to TextInput in RN docs

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass the color props only platform-specific then you can do it like this

```
// this will only create color props for ios only
const color = Platform.OS === 'ios' && { color: "#000" }

<TextInput
  value={this.state.username}
  placeholder={Languages.email}
  placeholderStyle={{
    fontFamily: Constants.headerRegular,
    color: '#A4A9AF',
  }}
  onChangeText={username => this.setState({ username })}
  label={Languages.userOrEmail}
  style={styles.textBox}
  
  // Now pass it to component like this
  {...color}
/>
```